# SimpleMemberShip MVC 4, makes 2 duplication SQL queries?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I don't know if this is something that's suppose to be happening or not, but after reviewing some of my application through MiniProfiler, I've noticed that SimpleMembership and Roles makes duplicate SQL queries to the server.

Here's the miniprofiler result:

```
http://localhost:49422/ActionMatrix/ActionMatrix?Length=0&D=23%2F03%2F2013&ProTyp=&ActTyp=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
T+3.7 ms
Scalar
0.3 ms
QueryValue QueryValue GetUserId GetRolesForUser
SELECT [UID] FROM [Usernames] WHERE (UPPER([User]) = @0)   
http://localhost:49422/ActionMatrix/ActionMatrix?Length=0&D=23%2F03%2F2013&ProTyp=&ActTyp=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
T+4.4 ms
Reader
0.2 ms
MoveNext Query Query GetRolesForUser
SELECT r.RoleName FROM webpages_UsersInRoles u, webpages_Roles r Where (u.UserId = @0 and u.RoleId = r.RoleId) GROUP BY RoleName   
http://localhost:49422/ActionMatrix/ActionMatrix?Length=0&D=23%2F03%2F2013&ProTyp=&ActTyp=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
T+5.1 ms
DUPLICATE Scalar
0.2 ms
QueryValue QueryValue GetUserId GetRolesForUser MoveNext HasClaim IsInRole
SELECT [UID] FROM [Usernames] WHERE (UPPER([User]) = @0)   
http://localhost:49422/ActionMatrix/ActionMatrix?Length=0&D=23%2F03%2F2013&ProTyp=&ActTyp=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
T+5.7 ms
DUPLICATE Reader
0.1 ms
MoveNext Query Query GetRolesForUser MoveNext HasClaim IsInRole
SELECT r.RoleName FROM webpages_UsersInRoles u, webpages_Roles r Where (u.UserId = @0 and u.RoleId = r.RoleId) GROUP BY RoleName
```

Maybe it checks twice? It definitely slows down page load. There's no global filter, and it's only passing through one "Authorize."
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
User.IsRole("roleName") or Roles.IsUserInRole("roleName")
```

i used :

```
Roles.FindUsersInRole("roleName", User.Identity.Name).Any()
```

its not the best query....

i think that is a bug...